# How to change the docker image installation directory?

Tags: docker

From what I can tell, docker images are installed to `/var/lib/docker` as they are pulled. Is there a way to change this location, such as to a mounted volume like `/mnt`?

Comment: which operating system is your docker running on?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50707738/move-docker-var-run-docker-data-to-different-directory

Answer (score 193, accepted):

With recent versions of Docker, you would set the value of the `data-root` parameter to your custom path, in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`
(according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file).

With older versions, you can change Docker's storage base directory (where container and images go) using the `-g`option when starting the Docker daemon. (check `docker --help`).
You can have this setting applied automatically when Docker starts by adding it to **/etc/default/docker**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you tell me the how to add this requirement in the docker upstart file? Is the case that I add the -g flag to the DOCKER_OPTS variable?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that was the file I was referring to. In '/etc/defaults/docker.io' there is a line 'DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4"'. Is that the option I should use to set the graph directory with the -g flag?

Comment: Yes, change this line to `DOCKER_OPTS="-dns 8.8.8.8 -dns 8.8.4.4 -g /mnt"`

Comment: Doesn't work in Fedora. See my answer if your distro is Fedora

Comment: You might need to implement this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30127580/docker-opts-in-etc-default-docker-ignored-on-debian8) to a bug in some versions of Debian or Ubuntu if docker ignores your `/etc/default/docker` file.

Comment: if you only want to change this setting only change to: 
`DOCKER_OPTS="-g /mnt"`
ommit the -dns parameters

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine. The problem is I get this error when downloading new images:

"failed to register layer: Untar re-exec error: exit status 1: output: link /bin/dnsdomainname /bin/domainname: operation not permitted"

Any ideas?

Comment: Setting this flag in /etc/default/docker is not recommended. There is a comment in the /etc/default/docker file pointing to this [guideline](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file).

Comment: Where is documented the `-g` option? I didn't find on the `dockerd` man page.

Comment: @ManoelVilela That's for old Docker releases - my initial answer was written 3 years ago ;)

Comment: It's still working on `17.09.0-ce`, but I didn't find yet any docs about that.

Comment: For further readers: this solution works on CentOS 7, with docker-ce server version 19.3

Comment: I tried a few different things, but editing the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` config is what ended up working for me. Good instructions here: https://evodify.com/change-docker-storage-location

Comment: Just don't forget to restart the docker daemon using `sudo systemctl restart docker` after changing `data-root` parameter

Answer (score 172):

Following advice from comments I utilize [Docker systemd documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/) to improve this answer.
Below procedure doesn't require reboot and is much cleaner.

First create directory and file for custom configuration:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
sudo $EDITOR /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-storage.conf
```

For docker version **before 17.06-ce** paste:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// --graph="/mnt"
```

For docker **after 17.06-ce** paste:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --data-root="/mnt"
```

#### Alternative method through `daemon.json`

I recently tried above procedure with **17.09-ce** on Fedora 25 and it seem to not work. Instead of that simple modification in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` do the trick:

```
{
    "graph": "/mnt",
    "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Despite the method you have to reload configuration and restart Docker:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

To confirm that Docker was reconfigured:

```
docker info|grep "loop file"
```

In recent version (17.03) different command is required:

```
docker info|grep "Docker Root Dir"
```

Output should look like this:

```
 Data loop file: /mnt/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /mnt/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
```

Or:

```
 Docker Root Dir: /mnt
```

Then you can safely remove old Docker storage:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

Comment: It's only method which helped me on Ubuntu 16.04!

Comment: This link https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/ explains how to configure Docker with systemd, which works for newer linux distribution such as Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The `docker info` statement is probably outdated. On Ubuntu 16.04, the check for reconfigured is `sudo docker info | grep "Docker Root Dir"`. Otherwise, good answer, should be the accepted one ;)

Comment: @GuillaumePerrot I just tested on Debian Sid with Docker 1.12.0 and still have `Data loop file` and `Metadata loop file`. Apparently on Ubuntu you have different version.

Comment: It worked for some time, but from some time I receive an error during starting the docker service:
`Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: invalid argument` (see https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14026).
After deleting `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-storage.conf` everything is OK. Probable reason was upgrading the kernel I did in the meantime.

Comment: Confirmed working May 26th, 2017 on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS with Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e.

Comment: On debian, the file to edit seems to be /lib/systemd/system/docker.service (see https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux).

Comment: In new version of Linux (4.10) and Docker (docker-ce 17.06) the line must be changed as follows:

/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --data-root="/mnt"

Comment: @lorenzo-bettini this is change in Docker. Kernel version is not related with that. Anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: be careful if you also have a _docker.conf_  in _/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/_

Comment: If you see `Docker Root Dir: /"/mnt"` when you runs `docker info|grep "Docker Root Dir"`, you have to replace `--data-root="/mnt"` into `--data-root=/mnt` inside the file `docker-storage.conf`

Comment: Note that the new storage location should not be an NTFS partition, see [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/23930), if you do want that use the vfs driver, but see mentioned thread for caveats.

Comment: /etc/docker/daemon.json works for 19.03.12, os Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 145):

For new docker versions we need to use `data-root` as `graph` is deprecated in v17.05.0: [official deprecated docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#-g-and---graph-flags-on-dockerd)

Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (if it doesn’t exist, create it) and include:

```
{
  "data-root": "/new/path/to/docker-data"
}
```

Then restart Docker with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

- A more detailed step-by-step explanation (including moving data) using Docker Storage with **data-root** can be found in: [Blog post](https://adriel.co.nz/blog/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/)
- In case of Windows a similar post [Windows specific](https://www.ntweekly.com/2019/09/20/how-to-change-docker-storage-data-folder-on-windows-server-2016/)

Comment: your comment helped me find this page:
https://adriel.co.nz/blog/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/

thanks!

Comment: I think it's time to give this answer the "accepted" flag, because it's working in the current version.

Comment: I comment here to let people know which version could use this, after https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/5978 release, It change officail website.

Comment: This is the correct answer for latest docker. I would just like to add, after adding changes to `daemon.json` and restarting docker service, just confirm that the path has been picked up by docker using `docker info|grep "Docker Root Dir"` (as mentioned by @piotr-kr in another answer)

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora 33. I didn't have the file, created it, works well.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 21.04. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Please note the original directory still exists **after** this change. It looks like it can be safely deleted `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker`.

Comment: Official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#daemon-data-directory

Answer (score 74):

#### Much easier way to do so:

Stop docker service

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

Move existing docker directory to new location

```
sudo mv /var/lib/docker/ /path/to/new/docker/
```

Create symbolic link

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/new/docker/ /var/lib/docker
```

Start docker service

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: This is IMO the right and the most straightforward solution - worked for me.

Comment: worked like a charm for me but without the trailing slash for the symbolic link command: `sudo ln -s /path/to/new/docker/ /var/lib/docker`

Comment: This is what the docker forums suggest: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-do-i-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/1169

Comment: This is an awesome solution which saved my life. :)

Comment: I've executed above and the docker was up and running. But I cannot find my docker images already exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: This shud be the top solution. This helped me in most convenient way

Answer (score 41):

Since I haven't found the correct instructions for doing this in Fedora (EDIT: people pointed in comments that this should also work on CentOS and Suse)  (/etc/default/docker isn't used there), I'm adding my answer here:

You  have to edit **/etc/sysconfig/docker**, and add the -g option in the OPTIONS variable. If there's more than one option, make sure you enclose them in "". In my case, that file contained:

```
OPTIONS=--selinux-enabled
```

so it would become

```
OPTIONS="--selinux-enabled -g /mnt"
```

After a restart (`systemctl restart docker`) , Docker should use the new directory

Comment: On CentOS 6.5/6.6 and probably 7, you use the same /etc/sysconfig/docker file, but you add the arguments to the variable name other_args.

Comment: The option is called DOCKER_OPTS now (docker version 1.7.0).

Comment: From version 1.8 of Docker onward, using the Docker configuration files in /etc/sysconfig is deprecated. Instead, you should use systemd drop-in configuration files in etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d.

After adding or modifying a drop-in file while the docker service is running, run the command systemctl daemon-reload to tell systemd to reload the configuration for the service. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/section_kfy_f2z_fp.html

Comment: and use drop-in files http://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/systemd/#custom-docker-daemon-options

Answer (score 24):

Don't use a symbolic Link to move the docker folder to /mnt (for example).
This may cause in trouble with the *docker rm* command.

Better use the -g Option for docker.
On Ubuntu you can set it permanently in /etc/default/docker.io. Enhance or replace the DOCKER_OPTS Line.

Here an example:
`DOCKER_OPTS="-g /mnt/somewhere/else/docker/"

Comment: in my case i had to restart

Comment: What kind of trouble do I have to expect with `docker rm` when using a symlink?

Comment: I also had to do this in `Ubuntu 16.04` http://stackoverflow.com/a/30219552/977622 to get it to work

Answer (score 15):

This solution works on **Red Hat 7.2 & Docker 1.12.0**

Edit the file
**/lib/systemd/system/docker.service** in your text editor.

add **-g /path/to/docker/** at the end of **ExecStart** directive. The complete line should look like this.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -g /path/to/docker/
```

Execute the below command

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

Execute the command to check docker directory

```
docker info | grep "loop file\|Dir"
```

If you have **/etc/sysconfig/docker** file in Red Hat or docker 1.7.1 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29002826/1290810) answer.

Comment: my case: centos7, latest docker; i had to call "systemctl status docker" to find the "docker.service" file and added the option "-g" like in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

In CentOS 6.5

```
service docker stop
mkdir /data/docker  (new directory)
vi /etc/sysconfig/docker
```

add following line

```
other_args=" -g /data/docker -p /var/run/docker.pid"
```

then save the file and start docker again

```
service docker start
```

and will make repository file in `/data/docker`

Answer (score 13):

Copy-and-paste version of the winner answer :)

Create this file with only this content:

**$ sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
  {
      "graph": "/my-docker-images"
  }
```

Tested on `Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS` in docker `1.12.6`

Comment: The `graph` attribute in daemon.json is deprecated as of v17.05.0, use `data-root` instead, cf.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50217666/743507

Answer (score 7):

This [blog post](https://blog.adriel.co.nz/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/) helps me

Here are the steps to change the directory even after you’ve created Docker containers etc.

Note, you don’t need to edit `docker.service` or `init.d` files, as it will read the change from the `.json` file mentioned below.

1. Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (if it doesn't exist, create it)
2. Add the following

```
{
  "data-root": "/new/path/to/docker-data"
}
```

3. Stop docker

```
sudo systemctl stop docker
```

4. Check docker has been stopped

```
ps aux | grep -i docker | grep -v grep
```

5. Copy the files to the new location

```
sudo rsync -axPS /var/lib/docker/ /new/path/to/docker-data
```

6. Start Docker back up

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```

7. Check Docker has started up using the new location

```
docker info | grep 'Docker Root Dir'
```

8. Check everything has started up that should be running

```
docker ps
```

9. Leave both copies on the server for a few days to make sure no issues arise, then feel free to delete it.

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker
```

Answer (score 6):

For Debian/Ubuntu or Fedora, you can probably use the other answers. But if you don't have files under `/etc/default/docker` or `/etc/sysconfig/docker`, and your system is running systemd, you may want to follow [this answer by h3nrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31817065/cannot-change-docker-image-directory). I am using Arch, and this works for me.

Basically, you need to configure systemd to read the new docker image location as an environment variable, and pass that environment variable into the Docker daemon execution script.

For completeness, here is h3nrick's answer:

---

Do you have a `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file?

If so, edit it so that the Docker service uses the usual `/etc/default/docker` as an environment file: `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker`.

In the `/etc/default/docker` file then add `DOCKER_OPTS="-g /home/rseixas/Programs/Docker/images"`.

At the end just do a `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker`.

For further information please also have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/).

Comment: If you follow current docker install instructions for Debian, you get SysVinit scripts but they aren't used. See https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/9889#issuecomment-109766580

Answer (score 6):

The official way of doing this based on this [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) guide and what I found while web-crawling is as follows:

1. Override the docker service conf:

   ```
    sudo systemctl edit docker.service
   ```
2. Add or modify the following lines, substituting your own values.

   ```
    [Service]
    ExecStart=
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph="/mnt/docker"
   ```

Save the file. (It creates: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf`)

3. Reload the `systemctl` configuration.

   ```
    sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Restart Docker.

   ```
    sudo systemctl restart docker.service
   ```

After this if you can nuke `/var/lib/docker` folder if you do not have any images there you care to backup.

Answer (score 5):

As recommneded by @mbarthelemy this can be done via the `-g` option when starting the docker daemon directly.

However, if docker is being started as a system service, it is not recommended to modify the `/etc/default/docker` file. There is a guideline to this located [here](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file).

The correct approach is to create an `/etc/docker/daemon.json` file on Linux (or Mac) systems or `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json` on Windows. If this file is not being used for anything else, the following fields should suffice:

```
{
    "graph": "/docker/daemon_files"
}
```

This is assuming the new location where you want to have docker persist its data is `/docker/daemon_files`

Answer (score 4):

A much simpler solution is to create a soft link point to whatever you want, such as

```
link -s /var/lib/docker /mnt/whatever
```

It works for me on my CentOS 6.5 server.

Comment: Don't create a softlink. Reasons see my comment I post before... You may run in trouble with 'docker rm' commands!

Comment: @suther: May? Now is there a situation you run into trouble or not? May is a bit imprecise for technical documentation, if I run into a problem then I want to learn when exactly that happens, how that problem is caused and how the outcome would be.

Answer (score 3):

I was having docker version 19.03.14. Below link helped me.

[Check this Link](https://blog.adriel.co.nz/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/)

in /etc/docker/daemon.json file I added below section:-

```
 {
    "data-root": "/hdd2/docker",
    "storage-driver": "overlay2"
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

On openSUSE Leap 42.1

```
$cat /etc/sysconfig/docker 
## Path           : System/Management
## Description    : Extra cli switches for docker daemon
## Type           : string
## Default        : ""
## ServiceRestart : docker
#
DOCKER_OPTS="-g /media/data/installed/docker"
```

Note that DOCKER_OPTS was initially empty and all I did was add in the argument to make docker use my new directory

Answer (score 2):

On Fedora 26 and probably many other versions, you may encounter an error after moving your base folder location as described above. This is particularly true if you are moving it to somewhere under /home. This is because SeLinux kicks in and prevents the docker container from running many of its programs from under this location.

The short solution is to remove the --enable-selinux option when you add the -g parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't that open room for attacks?

Answer (score 1):

On an AWS Ubuntu 16.04 Server I put the Docker images on a separate EBS, mounted on /home/ubuntu/kaggle/, under the docker dir

This snippet of my initialization script worked correctly

```
# where are the images initially stored?
sudo docker info | grep "Root Dir"
# ... not where I want them

# modify the configuration files to change to image location
# NOTE this generates an error
# WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use.
#          Use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` to specify a custom block storage device.
# see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620825/
#     warning-of-usage-of-loopback-devices-is-strongly-discouraged-for-production-use

sudo sed -i   ' s@#DOCKER_OPTS=.*@DOCKER_OPTS="-g /home/ubuntu/kaggle/docker"@ '  /etc/default/docker

sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /lib/systemd/system/docker.service
sudo cp  /lib/systemd/system/docker.service /etc/systemd/system/
sudo chmod -R ugo+rw /etc/systemd/system/

sudo sed -i ' s@ExecStart.*@ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd://@ '  /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
sudo sed -i '/ExecStart/a EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker' /etc/systemd/system/docker.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo docker info | grep "Root Dir"
# now they're where I want them
```

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users in the 17.06.0-ce-mac19 version you can simply move the Disk Image location from the user interface in the preferences option Just change the location of the disk image and it will work (by clicking **Move disk Image**) and restarting the docker. Using this approach I was able to use my external hardisk for storing docker images.

[image]

Comment: how about the existing files of docker? should we move it manually ?

Comment: You can try to re-install docker in a location of your preference. Image and docker files are independent.

Answer (score 0):

For Those looking in 2020. The following is for Windows 10 Machine:

1. In the global Actions pane of Hyper-V Manager click Hyper-V
   Settings…
2. Under Virtual Hard Disks change the location from the
   default to your desired location.
3. Under Virtual Machines change the
   location from the default to your desired location, and click apply.

[image]

4. Click OK to close the Hyper-V Settings page.