# Docker save issue

Tags: docker

I am on `docker` version `1.11.2`. I am trying to `docker save` an image but i get 
an error. 
i did `docker images` to see the size of the image and the result is this

`myimage             0.0.1-SNAPSHOT      e0f04657b1e9        10 months ago       1.373 GB`

The server I am on is low on space but it has `2.2 GB` available but when I run `docker save myimage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT > img.tar` i get 
`write /dev/stdout: no space left on device`

I removed all exited containers and dangling volumes in hopes of making it work but nothing helped.

Comment: Try reading this question to see if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device

Comment: @Daniel thats where i got the recommendation to delete the volumes and exited containers but no luck :(

Comment: Have you checked the /tmp free space and free memory ? I have seen situations where those were full and this ended in a misguiding error message like that you describe. You might want to pipe the output into gzip or netcat it to a server with more free space

Comment: @Marged `df /tmp`

`Filesystem              1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on`

`/dev/mapper/centos-root  50808832 48607856   2200976  96% /`

Comment: @Marged so looks like there isnt enough in there, what are my options? one suggestion was to create a temporary `/tmp` but idk if that is safe, I'm on the production server

Comment: Alternatively, gzip it on the fly: `docker save myimage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT | gzip > img.tar.gz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have no enough space left on device. So free some more space or try gzip on the fly:

```
docker save myimage:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT | gzip > img.tar.gz
```

To restore it, docker automatically realizes that is gziped:

```
docker load < img.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 1):

In such a situation where you can't free enough space locally you might want to use storage available over a network connection. A little bit more difficult to set up are NFS or Samba.

The easiest approach could be piping the output through netcat, but keep in mind that this is at least by default unencrypted.

But as long as your production server is that low on space you are vulnerable to a bunch of other problems.
Until you can provide more free space I wouldn't create files locally, zipped or not. You could bring important services down when you run out of free space.