# Not enough space during build

Tags: docker

I am currently trying to create docker image with python files and lot of extra packages in requirement.txt.

While I am running the command "sudo docker build -t XXX ." the packages are downloaded and than installed one by one untill I receive an error:
"Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 28] No space left on device"

I have already did the atomic option of "sudo docker system prune" and all the past docker images are deleted.

Moreover, "sudo docker info" shows that I have 15 GB allocated to docker and while my unsuccesfull docker image size is 1 GB size it is still well below the total memory.

None of the options mentioned here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203168/docker-says-no-space-left-on-device-but-system-has-plenty-of-space
or here: [Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device)
worked. I can create several "failed" dockers of ~1GB with the total size of more than 20GB so it is not an issue of lack of space on my HDD of VM.
So I would be grateful for some more ideas.

Comment: could you post the output of this command `df -h`?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/bastman/5b57ddb3c11942094f8d0a97d461b430

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The disk partition used by Docker is becoming full during the build. You can see the available and used space on your partitions using `df -h`. You can either add more space to that partition or you need to clean more files.

The `docker system prune` only removes unused data (dangling images, unreferences volumes ...). You can clean more space, by deleting images that you don't need. I suggest you take a look at the images you have using `docker image ls` and explicitly delete unneeded ones using `docker image rm <image>`.

Comment: got the same error although the `data_root` is configured to a large partition and after pruning. The only explanation I find is that docker creates temp files on my (small) root partition while building. Is it possible to change that in the config ?

Comment: You just saved mi computer! 25 GB in trash images!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Docker Desktop on Mac, go to Preferences and increase the Disk image size. In my case it was displaying that it was full `Disk image size: 59.6 GB (59.6 GB used)`.

Comment: Thanks for offering the answer. But you refer to a Preferences option for Docker Desktop. Are you perhaps on a Mac? I am on Windows and don't see that (I see "Settings"...but even in there we have no option to modify the disk size except via a config file.) I'm simply proposing that if you ARE on a Mac, it seems it would help future readers if you simply tweaked the answer to add "on macOS", before your first comma.