# MongoDB no space left on device with docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

My MongoDB gets stuck and returning the following error:

```
2019-01-28T18:28:53.419+0000 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (28) [1548700133:419188][1:0x7feecb0ae700], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: /data/db/WiredTiger.turtle.set: handle-open: open: No space left on device
2019-01-28T18:28:53.419+0000 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (22) [1548700133:419251][1:0x7feecb0ae700], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: WiredTiger.wt: the checkpoint failed, the system must restart: Invalid argument
2019-01-28T18:28:53.419+0000 E STORAGE  [WTCheckpointThread] WiredTiger error (-31804) [1548700133:419260][1:0x7feecb0ae700], file:WiredTiger.wt, WT_SESSION.checkpoint: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
2019-01-28T18:28:53.419+0000 F -        [WTCheckpointThread] Fatal Assertion 28558 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 361
2019-01-28T18:28:53.419+0000 F -        [WTCheckpointThread]

***aborting after fassert() failure

2019-01-28T18:28:53.444+0000 F -        [WTCheckpointThread] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).
```

However, my disk has space:

df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            992M     0  992M   0% /dev
tmpfs           200M  5.7M  195M   3% /run
/dev/xvda1       39G   26G   14G  66% /
tmpfs          1000M  1.1M  999M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs          1000M     0 1000M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           200M     0  200M   0% /run/user/1000
```

df -i

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            253844     322 253522    1% /dev
tmpfs           255835     485 255350    1% /run
/dev/xvda1     5120000 5090759  29241  100% /
tmpfs           255835      10 255825    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           255835       3 255832    1% /run/lock
tmpfs           255835      16 255819    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           255835       4 255831    1% /run/user/1000
```

And this would be my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:

# MariaDB
    mariadb:
        container_name: mariadb
        image: mariadb
        ports: ['3306:3306']
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - /home/ubuntu/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PasswordGoesHere"
        command:
            # - --memory=1536M
            - --wait_timeout=28800
            - --innodb_buffer_pool_size=1g
            - --innodb_buffer_pool_instances=4
            # - --innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size=1073741824

# APACHE
    apache:
        container_name: apache
        image: apache-php7.1
        ports: ['80:80', '443:443']
        restart: always
        entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
        volumes:
            - /home/ubuntu/apache2/apache-config:/etc/apache2/sites-available/
            - /home/ubuntu/apache2/www:/var/www/html/

# MONGODB
    mongodb:
        container_name: mongodb
        image: mongo
        ports: ['27017:27017']
        restart: always
        command:
            - --auth
        volumes:
            - /home/ubuntu/moongodb:/data/db
```

Would it be a problem with my docker-compose.yml? Because I'm using the physical disk and not virtual. I can run the applications and after 1-2 hours the mongo will fail again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running this in centos/RHEL/Amazon Linux you should know that the devicemapper has major issues with releasing inodes in Docker.

Even if you prune the entire docker system, it will still hang on to a lot of inodes, the only way to really solve this is to basically implode docker:

```
service docker stop
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
service docker start
```

This should release all your inodes.

I've spent a lot of time on this, Docker really only fully supports Ubuntu overlay2, and the devicemapper, although works, is technically not supported.

Comment: I did as you said, we'll see us next if it will work. :)

Comment: Could you complete your information with @akhan response? Both information is required for response. So, I leave as a solution to my doubt.

Answer (score 9):

### Clean docker cache - volumes & containers

for me it works:

```
docker system prune
```

and then

```
docker volume prune
```

---

or in one line:

```
docker system prune --volumes
```

To see all volumes :  `docker volume ls`

To show docker disk usage: `docker system df`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like 100% of your inodes are in use (from the `df -i` output). Try looking for [dangling volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/#dangling) and [cleaning them up](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_prune/). Also, it would be a good idea to make sure the docker daemon is using a production-grade storage driver ([about storage drivers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/), [choosing a storage driver](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/)).

Comment: I already run the `docker system pruner`, and there was no difference

Comment: "It looks like 100% of your inodes are in use (from the df -i output)." - Would that be a problem?

Comment: Yes, inodes are an essential component of Linux/Unix/Mac filesystems. This [article](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Inodes.html) is a good introduction.

Comment: Could you complete your information with @Avamore response? Both information is required for response. So, I leave as a solution to my doubt.