# docker import with Docker for Windows using Linux containers no space left on device error with Storage Driver: overlay2

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I'm importing a large database image at 15 GB (I can import an image of 9.5 GB without a problem.) with Docker for Windows using Linux containers. I'm using `Windows 10 Pro 1803, build 17134.1006`.

Error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker import "C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\MSSQL.tar" mssql
Error response from daemon: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /var/opt/mssql/data/TestDatabase.mdf: no space left on device
```

I have removed all dangling volumes and unused images as suggested here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37287054/3850405

When reading about storage drivers I came across some limitations for `devicemapper` and other drivers.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#options-per-storage-driver

For `devicemapper`:

> Specifies the size to use when creating the base device, which limits
>   the size of images and containers. The default value is 10G. Note,
>   thin devices are inherently “sparse”, so a 10G device which is mostly
>   empty doesn’t use 10 GB of space on the pool. However, the filesystem
>   will use more space for the empty case the larger the device is.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#dmbasesize

I can't find any image limitation for `overlay2`, only 20 GB limit for containers as default.

> Specifies the size to use when creating the sandbox which is used for
>   containers. Defaults to 20G.

I tried to run the example command but I got an error. dockerd is not mapped to command.

```
C:\>dockerd --storage-opt size=40G
'dockerd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#size

Since it should work anyway I'm not sure I'm on the right path there.

System information:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker --version
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker info
Client:
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 5
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 5
 Images: 8
 Server Version: 19.03.2
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 894b81a4b802e4eb2a91d1ce216b8817763c29fb
 runc version: 425e105d5a03fabd737a126ad93d62a9eeede87f
 init version: fec3683
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.184-linuxkit
 Operating System: Docker Desktop
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 3.837GiB
 Name: docker-desktop
 ID: XD32:TQJ4:EKWP:BPE4:ETXW:XFXE:LB3L:J4WB:PCFR:DAXK:MJ62:47RI
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: true
  File Descriptors: 28
  Goroutines: 42
  System Time: 2019-09-17T10:00:50.1259999Z
  EventsListeners: 1
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
 Product License: Community Engine
```

Storage space should not be an issue:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should learn to read... read it as 55.29 GB unused. After increasing Disk image max size in Docker -> Settings -> Advanced everything started working.

[image]