# Docker Jenkins - no space left on AWS EC2 with docker pull error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

I try to pull an image from a public  registry to a machine.

The image is a Jenkins  image. The machine is AWS EC2, with 450 GB hard drive.

When attempting to run the docker command , it gives following error.

```
failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicutu.a: no space left on device
```

Upon checking the space on Tapan Banker machine

```
Filesystem                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                          3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs                             3.7G   16K  3.7G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                             3.7G   33M  3.7G   1% /run
tmpfs                             3.7G     0  3.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-rootVol     10G  2.3G  7.8G  23% /
/dev/nvme0n1p1                   1014M  334M  681M  33% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-homeVol    3.0G   33M  3.0G   2% /home
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-varVol     4.0G  3.5G  588M  86% /var
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-tmpVol     2.0G   58M  2.0G   3% /tmp
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-logVol     4.0G   36M  4.0G   1% /var/log
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-auditVol   4.0G   98M  3.9G   3% /var/log/audit
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-vartmpVol  2.0G   33M  2.0G   2% /var/tmp
tmpfs                             753M     0  753M   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                             753M     0  753M   0% /run/user/0
```

Posted by Tapan Nayan Banker, [www.tapanbanker.com](https://www.tapanbanker.com)

Comment: `The machine is AWS EC2, with 450 GB hard drive.` I don't see it has 450G

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: can you paste output of `df -ih`

Comment: Also check where is docker storing the image. Is it `/var/lib/docker` ?