# Docker mount local directory for rclone

Tags: docker

I am downloading data using a Docker rclone such like

```
docker container run -v ~/.config/rclone/:/root/.config/rclone/ ddzhangzz/rclone rclone copy -P drive:/mydata/checkSize.xls ./
```

But got error for space

```
docker: Error response from daemon: write `/var/lib/docker/image/btrfs/layerdb/mounts/2685a4ccbb645539ceddec4db61ef3d1cc82d5e961b5b0d225aacf105ac4fd1f/mount-id: no space left on device.                                                     See 'docker run --help'.`
```

My question is how to mount current directory to Docker so that the data download directly to current folder?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/36584376/5666087 or https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-no-space-left-on-device/69205 help? Those links suggest using [`docker system prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/).

Comment: I am running on server and don't have root privilege or I should avoid throught root.