# How to fix gitlab docker no disk space left error?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am building a docker image of an application using the GitLab ci pipeline and when the docker build command is running, I am getting this error:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/src/app/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_fgZvnM: no space left on device
```

And this error is occuring during the COPY .. command. I don't have any idea how to fixx it. If anyone knows please tell.

Thanks & Regards
Piyush

Comment: Check docker host's free disk space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly try running `docker image prune` to clean up all dangling images on your machine.

If the issue still persists then check this :

[Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: Do I write that inside the .yaml file? Wouldn't that require Docker in Docker?