# How do I fix No space left on device error from postgres in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to write a query that is going to be updating a lot of rows but I keep hitting

```
ERROR:  could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp441.1627": No space left on device
```

I imagine that this is because I don't have enough space in my docker container but all of this is new to me so I'm not really sure if there is something obvious I'm missing. How would I go about seeing how much space I currently have and how would I increase it?

This is my docker compose file

```
version: "3"
services:
  db-15:
    image: postgres:15
    ports:
      - "55432:5432"
    volumes:
      - app-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

  db-13:
    image: postgres:13
    ports:
      - "55433:5432"
    volumes:
      - app-db-data-13:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres

volumes:
  app-db-data:
  app-db-data-13:
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I hit the `no space left on device` issue for Docker its because I have too many images, volumes etc. on my local machine and I need to clear things up by running a `docker system prune` like mentioned in here:
https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-no-space-left-on-device/69205/4

or

[Docker error : no space left on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604846/docker-error-no-space-left-on-device)

Answer (score 0):

You are running a bad SQL statement that writes enough temporary files to fill your disk. You should set the PostgreSQL parameter `temp_file_limit` to something that is way less than the amount of free space on your file system.

But that won't fix the cause of the problem, it will only prevent you from running out of disk space, which is not a good condition for a relational database. You will have to fix the statement the generates that many temporary files — perhaps you forgot a join condition or two?