# Creating a Docker volume at a specific location

Tags: docker, storage

Can I tell Docker to create a volume at a specific location on the host machine?

The host machine has some storage restrictions and I'd like the volume to be stored in `/data` instead of `/var/lib/docker/vfs/dir/`.

This isn't even mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) so I suspect I misunderstood something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to use a  different directory than the default `/var/lib/docker` as Docker runtime? You can do this by starting docker daemon with `-g` option and path to the  directory of your choice. From the man page:

```
-g, --graph=""
     Path to use as the root of the Docker runtime. Default is /var/lib/docker.
```

Comment: Ok, it might be the solution, though it's still moving the whole Docker runtime, not just my volume.

Comment: I found some complementary information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory).

Comment: I don't think you can move just the volume part of it to `/data` and still keep the runtime under `/var/lib/docker`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the way docker works means you can't control where volumes go at a container level like that.

Answer (score 0):

When firing up your container with "docker run":

```
 docker run -v /data/some_directory:/mount/location/in/your/container your_docker_image
```

You cannot do this in the same way via `Dockerfile` because of portability.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. I don't want a shared directory, I just want a different location for my `vfs` volume.

Comment: Ah, ok. I think that's something that'd be more related to your docker installation on this host, rather than individual containers/images, so I'd be thinking either symlink or mount `/data` into that location.

Comment: Maybe there's something to that, but the other answer looks much more promising.