# Cannot change Docker image directory

Tags: docker, virtual-machine

I am using Fedora 22 and I must change my Docker image directory from

> /var/lib/docker

to

> /home/my_user/docker

Following this 
[How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory) I edited the /etc/sysconfig/docker adding:

> other_args="-g /home/rseixas/Programs/Docker/images"

I restarted the service but no change. In fact I restarted my machine and I am not able to see it changing.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you have a `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file?

If so, edit it so that the Docker service uses the usual `/etc/default/docker` as an environment file: `EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker`.

In the `/etc/default/docker` file then add `DOCKER_OPTS="-g /home/rseixas/Programs/Docker/images"`.

At the end just do a `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart docker`.

For further information please also have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/articles/systemd/).

Answer (score 6):

In `docker` `1.8+` the service file settings changed a little:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
# in docker 1.7 use ExecStart:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd://
# in docker 1.8 use ExecStart:
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd://
MountFlags=slave
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=infinity
```

& some other notes for [Debian / Fedora with the latest `docker` & a custom directory](https://it-offshore.co.uk/linux/debian/37-docker-1-7-on-debian-ubuntu).