# Caching docker images locally

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I work in a Docker container that has a bunch of other Docker containers running inside. Every time the outer container is destroyed, I see that the images that were previously pulled from Docker Hub have to be pulled again.

In the example of Redis, I see the following

```
docker run --name my_redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
Unable to find image 'redis:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/redis
```

and the process is taking a while to complete.

Is there a way to cache Redis so that the outer container can pick it up? Perhaps I just need to volume mount appropriate directories. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you _just need to volume mount appropriate directories_.

Comment: @jangroth So which one is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two options:

- Use `docker -g` to configure where your inner docker instance stores its images. Make sure that this is a location outside of the inner docker instance that doesn't get blown away. Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory).
- Run a private docker registry that caches images locally. See [here](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/) for details.

And a [word of warning](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/) about running docker in docker.