# Put docker image into user local directory

Tags: docker

I am trying to use docker in the following way:

1. the basic image, e.g. `debian:latest`, uses the system default place, i.e. `/var/lib/docker`, to store its image.
2. the image above it, e.g. `mongodb`, uses my home directory `/home/xis/`

From [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory) I know how to move *ALL* images, but I wish to move part of the images only.

Comment: What is your goal? Saving disk space, allowing you to easily change the contents of a running image, or something else?

Comment: @BMich The server is used by different accounts, I want different accounts have different services in different containers, with different quotas.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to "export" the image to a tar file and put it wherever you want.  Do "man docker-export" to see how to use it.