# Docker: How to store images and metadata on another filesystem?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

This issue has been really giving me grief and I would appreciate some help.

Running docker 1.10.3 on a vanilla Centos7.1 box, I have two file systems, a 15gb dev/vda1 where my root and var/lib is and a 35gb /dev/vdc1 mounted on mnt where I would like to put my docker volumes/image data and meta data. This is for administration and management purposes as I am expecting the number of containers to grow.

Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/vda1 15G 1.5G 13G 11% /

devtmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev

tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /dev/shm

tmpfs 1.9G 8.3M 1.9G 1% /run

tmpfs 1.9G 0 1.9G 0% /sys/fs/cgroup

/dev/vdc1 35G 49M 33G 1% /mnt/vdc1

tmpfs 385M 0 385M 0% /run/user/0

Despite all my attempts, docker keep on installing and defaulting to place the Data Space and Meta data space onto the 15gb root volume. I have tried many solutions including ; http://collabnix.com/archives/5881 , [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory1), and more, all with no luck.... basically wither the docker instance does not start at or all it does with its default settings.

Would like some help either the settings required for Data and Meta data to be stored on /mnt/vdc1 or install docker as a whole on the drive.

Thanks in advance , bf !

Comment: What command do you use to start docker?

Comment: systemctl start docker

Answer (score 0):

`--graph` is only one flag. There is also `--exec-root` and `$DOCKER_TMPDIR` which are used to store files as well.

```
DIR=/mnt/vdc1
export DOCKER_TMPDIR=$DIR/tmp
dockerd -D -g $DIR --exec-root=$DIR
```