# How to change the Docker image installation directory on Mac?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

Docker images are stored in `$HOME/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data` but how to move those large files to an external drive for example? I have tried symbolic link, it didn't work. Also I couldn't find the `-g`option for `docker` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

All you have to do is go to preferences

[image]

Then Disk and click at "move disk image"

[image]

Select the folder you want to move to, awaits it completes and you are done.

Comment: This option seems to have been removed from Docker Desktop

Comment: I cant find the option to chose path :-(

Comment: @Bruno this solution does not work as  I don't see this option with more recent versions of docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Docker Desktop (around 4.18 until now) is having issues with **Disk image location** configuration.
It will hang forever if you change this path via Docker Desktop Settings.
But there's a workaround to modify it via `~/.docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
  "data-root": "/path/to/new/directory"
}
```

Exit Docker Desktop and restart again. Please note that Docker may start with empty data.