# Change Docker Root Dir on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker

There is already a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467032/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory-on-mac) about this but the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

My Docker Desktop app is using the directory below:

```
/Users/guilpejon/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data
```

And `docker info` gives me this:

```
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
```

The question is, how do I change the `Docker Root Dir` to use the same directory used by the Docker Desktop app?

Comment: The `docker info` directory is inside the VM contained in the first location you show.  I suspect on MacOS the `docker info` will _always_ be that exact location, but it's not related to any location on your outer host system.

Comment: You could be right, but it's weird because my containers do not show up on Docker Desktop either, so I'm guessing it is pointing to a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

With docker command you can use --data-root option to provide path of root directory.

Also in docker Preference > Docker Engine option you can provide configuration for docker demon in JSON config. You need to copy content from existing root directory to new directory.

For more option refer https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion but ended up doing a docker factory reset because of an error during the process. That reset actually fixed my original problem, so I documented it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow Nilesh's answer but Docker Desktop gave me an error while trying to do this:

```
{
  "features": {
    "buildkit": true
  },
  "experimental": false,
  "data-root": "/Users/guilpejon/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/data"
}
```

On the error pop up window, I chose to reset docker to factory settings and then the Docker Root Dir changed to `/var/lib/docker`, which works for me.

Now I can control docker's resources through Docker Desktop app again, which is what I wanted.

Comment: Well, nevermind. This worked for a few moments but now all of my new terminal tabs are opening with Docker Root Dir "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker" again