# 'No space left on device' after I changed Docker's storage base directory with DOCKER_OPTIONS

Tags: docker

I changed Docker's storage base directory from `/var/lib/docker` to `/home/docker` by changing `DOCKER_OPTIONS` in `/etc/default/docker` as explained in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24312133/957997). After that, I rsynced the old `/var/lib/docker` to the new place.

Here is my Docker configuration file:

```
# Docker Upstart and SysVinit configuration file
# ....

# Customize location of Docker binary (especially for development testing).
#DOCKER="/usr/local/bin/docker"

# Use DOCKER_OPTS to modify the daemon startup options.
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 -g /home/docker"

# If you need Docker to use an HTTP proxy, it can also be specified here.
#export http_proxy="http://127.0.0.1:3128/"

# This is also a handy place to tweak where Docker's temporary files go.
#export TMPDIR="/mnt/bigdrive/docker-tmp"
```

Everything was working fine after I rebooted. However, I started getting a "no space left on device" in my containers from time to time. When this error happens, if my container is up, I can't even do a `mkdir`. If the container is down and I try to start it, I get the following:

> Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime
>   error: could not synchronise with container process: can't create
>   pivot_root dir , error mkdir .pivot_root: no space left on device"

However, I have space:

```
Filesystem                                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                           32G  4,0K   32G   1% /dev
tmpfs                                         6,3G  1,6M  6,3G   1% /run
/dev/sda1                                      92G   56G   32G  64% /
none                                          4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                          5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                                           32G  472K   32G   1% /run/shm
none                                          100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda5                                     1,6T  790G  762G  51% /home
```

I'm suspecting that perhaps I haven't done the storage migration correctly. Does someone know what might be happening?

Comment: What does `df -i` show.

Comment: Sorry for leave you hanging. A while later after I posted this question, we checked `df -i` and found that the inodes were 100% full (108kk inodes). I wasn't expecting that. It had nothing to do with moving the storage directory. Now, I'm not sure if I should keep this question or delete it.

Comment: Others may find it helpful. I'll post an answer based on your findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running out of disk space can also include inode limits. You can check those with `df -i`. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem) on Unix.SE walks you through the steps required to increase the number of inodes available. Short of that, you can delete files to free up the inodes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try cleaning up images that aren't in use. This fixed the problem for me:

```
docker images -aq -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker rmi
```

As well as volumes. This will remove dangling volumes:

```
docker volume ls -q -f 'dangling=true' | xargs docker volume rm
```

https://success.docker.com/article/error-message-no-space-left-on-device-in-default-machine