# docker not responding when using different data directory

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04, docker-image

I want to change the image directory in docker. I tried the initial two methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory). Both methods work and change the directory for docker images. But the problem is that the images stop responding. I can run the hello world example but if I run the ubuntu container or the whalesay container, docker stops responding and I can't run it again.

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash

docker run docker/whalesay cowsay boo
```

On using the above commands, the images get downloaded and nothing happens. Then I enter the command again to run and the system stops responding. I used Ctrl + C to terminate it but after that I can not open any other terminal screen. Also, the system doesn't power off; it gets stuck at a black screen. On force restarting the system docker starts failing to run giving  the following log:

```
docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-14 20:12:14 EDT; 10min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1160 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1160 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux dockerd[1160]: unable to configure the Docker daemon with file /etc/docker/daemon.json: EOF
Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 14 20:12:14 abmittal-linux systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
```

Removing and reinstalling docker also doesn't work if the directory is same as before (even if the directory has been deleted and then made again). I have to change the directory in the configuration to get it to run again but again it stops responding.

The following is my daemon.json file:

```
{
    "graph":"/mnt/other/docker_images"
}
```

EDIT: I think I may have found the error. The partition /mnt/other is using NTFS file system (and is on a different disk). Can someone please confirm if this might be the source of the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: [Link](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25328)
I tried creating a custom directory on an ext4 partition and it worked.