# Pull docker image to different location..?

Tags: unix, docker

docker pull image_name

downloads the image to the default location. What if i want to download the same image to different location of my wish..!? what option i need to use while executing `docker pull`.

Regards,
Rohith

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any options on the `docker pull` command to change the download location.

You can configure the storage location on the docker daemon itself (according to [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory)).

By default images will be stored in `/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/<id>` in most cases (according to [Where are Docker images stored on the host machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234831/where-are-docker-images-stored-on-the-host-machine)).

Comment: atleast do we have an option to rename the image while pulling itself - my intention was to download the same image which is already present., and measure the time taken to download the new image from the repository.

Comment: I don't think so, you can see the `docker pull` docs here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pull/. You could remove the download of the image with `docker image rm` (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_rm/) and redo it while timing.

Comment: from the first link: set it in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` `"data-root": "/media/user/disk/docker"`