# change docker container's root direcotry

Tags: docker

Is there a way to change where the container's root directory to be mounted? The reason is currently it is mounted to /dev/mapper/sysvg-root.vol, which does not have much space left.

```
root@f967e2f116fe:/# df -h
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                      10G  6.9G  3.2G  69% /
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/sysvg-root.vol   10G  6.9G  3.2G  69% /etc/hosts
shm                          64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                        32G     0   32G   0% /sys/firmware
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory)

Comment: Thanks. But I am not the system admin...