# Configure the path to where docker loads images

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia-jetson

I am working on `NVidia Jetson TX2`. Unfortunately there are only about 16 GBs of storage left for my work, and an image of about this size to load to the docker.

I've tried adding a SD card to the machine - I saved the image file on the SD card and tried to load it using the command line `sudo ./tx2-docker load -i /media/nvidia/3038-3638/jetson_docker/lpr_image.img` (`tx2-docker` is this wrapping [script](https://github.com/Technica-Corporation/Tegra-Docker/blob/master/bin/tx2-docker)).

Though, i got the following error:

```
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): write /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libflite_cmu_us_awb.so.2.0.0: no space left on device
```

Meaning, i still don't have enough storage.

I think that maybe storing the image on the SD card, and loading the image such that all files created by docker will be dumped to some folder to the SD might help.

***TL;DR / The question***

So, my question is - Is there a way to configure `Docker` such that when an image is loaded (in my case, a `.img` file), all files created will be dumped to some specified path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory)