# Need to remove symbolic link I created for /var/lib/docker/ but can't find it. Unable to use docker and feel helpless

Tags: docker, symlink

I'm feeling really terrible atm so any help would be really appreciated. I kept running out of space when downloading docker images on /var, so I decided I needed to change the location for where docker was installing images. I tried several methods but had no success. First, I tried creating daemon.json in etc/docker and mapping data-root to a place with more storage (data2/docker). I stopped docker, moved everything over, made the file, but no dice. The docker daemon wouldn't start.
Then, I saw this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/49743270/13034460 which involves creating a symbolic link between /var/lib/docker and the new directory (data2/docker). I followed his instructions:

> Much easier way to do so:
>
> Stop docker service: `sudo systemctl stop docker`
>
> Move existing docker directory to new location `sudo mv /var/lib/docker/ /path/to/new/docker/`
>
> Create symbolic link
> `sudo ln -s /path/to/new/docker/ /var/lib/docker`
>
> Start docker service
> `sudo systemctl start docker`

Well, this didn't work for me. I can't find the error message b/c it's too far up in my terminal, but it was along the lines of "you don't have enough storage/we don't know where to store this image". /data2/docker should have tons of storage so that can't be the issue.

But the **big** problem now is that this symbolic link exists and I can't figure out how to get rid of it. I tried removing everything related to docker on the computer, uninstalling, then reinstalling docker (which always used to work for me if there were any issues). But when I reinstall, it won't even run docker hello-world b/c of the link (I think). I get a message:

```
docker: open /data2/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob289478576: no such file or directory
```

So...it's looking in data2/docker because of the symbolic link (I assume), but that directory doesn't exist anymore. But neither does /var/lib/docker! All I want is to delete this link and get everything back to fresh defaults. I can worry about the storage issue another time. If I can't use docker at all, I'm so screwed. I've tried looking in every directory to find the link using -ls -l, but I can't find it.  I used the exact code that the above references when I created the link (just my paths instead).

I would be so grateful to anyone who could help--I'm so lost on this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you check `/data2/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob289478576` really exists there? COuld you check your `/data2/docker/tmp/` folder has any files?

Comment: data2/docker is completely empty

Comment: You should be able to just `sudo rm /var/lib/docker`, if it's a symlink.  But if you're seeing messages that explicitly reference a `/data2` path, it's more likely you've modified the Docker daemon configuration; try looking for changes in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` or try running `sudo systemctl edit docker.service`.  (Looking at [Post-installation steps for Linux](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/) in the Docker docs.)

Comment: strangely /var/lib/docker is gone, and so is /etc/docker. a bit confused what editing docker.service would do even after reading the docs

Comment: After doing the symbolic link, no modification to `daemon.json` should be needed. So you need to reset or remove the daemon.json file (its original state), and run docker again, or re-install it if nothing works.

Comment: `daemon.json` is gone. maybe I need to make a new empty one? as I mentioned, `etc/docker` is gone. Edit: creating a docker directory and empty daemon.json worked to at least get /var/lib/docker back. Thanks!!