# can I move a single docker image to another directory?

Tags: docker

I'd like to keep some less used images on an external disk.
Is that possible?
Or should I move all images to an external disk changing some base path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Docker images are stored in an opaque, backend-specific format inside the `/var/lib/docker` directory.  You can't move some of the images to a different location, only the entire Docker storage tree.  See for example [How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory).

If you have images you only rarely use, you can `docker rmi` them for now and then `docker pull` them again from Docker Hub or another repository when you need them.