# Specifying where Docker stores/places files on Linux VM

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

Relatively new to Docker so trying to understand how to accomplish my task.

Locally, I:

1. Build the image
2. Push the image to some URL
3. SSH into Linux VM
4. `docker pull` image from URL
5. `docker run image_name`

This image, when run, downloads 2 fairly large csv.gz's. When unzipped, the two CSV's are about 15GB each.

I set up `/app` on the Linux VM to have 200GB available. So, in short, I need to have the Docker image download those 2 CSV's there. However no matter what I've tried within my `Dockerfile`, I see

'No space left on device' when it gets to the part to download the CSVs.

I've tried to set `WORKDIR` to `/app`, but that does not help.

Do I need to use a `daemon.json` file? Does some sort of Docker setting need to be changed on the Linux VM? Do I need to look into Docker volumes?

Relevant pieces of Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos/python-36-centos7
USER root
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
```

As for `/usr/src/app`, I've never seen anything in there. I normally use `/usr/src/app` since that's what I use for my Cloud Foundry deployments.

Any insight to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you downloading the files during build? If so that would be a bad design. You should be doing the download during the run. Also you should use volumes to make sure `/app` is mapped to outside

Comment: Nah downloaded during the docker run, not the build. Yea been looking into volumes. I keep seeing the CSVs going to `/var/lib/docker/overlay.../usr/src/app/` using `docker run -d -v myvolume:/app IMAGE python3 main.py ARG_HERE` What do you mean by mapped to outside?

Comment: Map a host folder and not a named volume. So something like `-v /usr/app:/app ....`

Comment: Ok that makes sense. The partially downloaded CSVs still showing up in `/usr/src/app` though. Should `WORKDIR` in the Dockerfile still be `/usr/src/app`?

Comment: WOKRDIR is unrelated, it decides what is the current directory when someone goes inside the container. So that depends on you

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following resolved the issue:

Create (if daemon.json does not exist): `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

And write

```
{ 
  “data-root”: “/app” 
}
```

Looks like by default everything goes to `/var`, and in my case, `/var` only has 4GB of space. `/app` is where the 200GB resides.

You will have to restart docker service when creating/saving daemon.json.

Referenced this answer: [the one with 88 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory/50217666#50217666)