# Store docker images and containers/data in different directories

Tags: docker, image, containers, storage

We are running a server with docker to encapsulate different functionalities. Some of these require quite large images. The server got 1 TB of SSD and 4 TB of HDD storage. I'd like to store running containers and their data on the SSD for performance but images on the HDD to preserve storage space.

I searched and found several solutions to moving the entire docker storage directory to a different volume, e.g.
[How to change the docker image installation directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309526/how-to-change-the-docker-image-installation-directory)
However, as far as I can tell this affects both images and running containers.

Poking around in /var/lib/docker/ I found almost the entire space taken up by the overlay2 directory, apparently the file system of the docker daemon. I must admit I do not fully understand how this works. I was able to reclaim about 150 GB of space by removing dangling images but could not find a way to move only the images to a different directory.

My question is how to do this or why it is not possible/reasonable. I'm rather new to docker, and would really appreciate an explanation on how the storage system actually works.